# Is it possible to not have a default country?

Tags: addresses, default-settings

I'm working on a Civi implementation for a client who deals with contacts around the world. It makes no real sense for them to have a default country, yet it looks like I have no option but to set one. Is there a way to not have a default country for address records?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CiviCRM allows you to over-ride the settings through php. You can over-ride default value for Contact Country.

Add the below snippet in your sites civicrm.settings.php file

```
global $civicrm_setting;
$civicrm_setting['Localization Preferences']['defaultContactCountry'] = '';
```

Ref: [Override CiviCRM Settings](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/settings/)

HTH

Pradeep